# implementing openiddict to dotnet core Grpc

Tags: .net-core, grpc, openiddict

Is there a way to implement openiddict to a dotnet core Grpc service, I added the following in Startup.cs :

```
            services.AddOpenIddict().AddCore(options => {
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                       .UseDbContext<DBContext>();
            }).AddServer(options => {
                options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
                options.AllowPasswordFlow()
                       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
                options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
            }).AddValidation(options =>{
                options.EnableAuthorizationValidation();
            });
```

also added in Configure:

```
          app.UseAuthentication();
          app.UseAuthorization();
```

How do can I get `GetOpenIddictServerRequest` in my service and generate a token?

Answer (score 1):

> How do can I get GetOpenIddictServerRequest in my service and generate a token?

Being able to return authorization or token responses from an arbitrary gRPC service is not a supported scenario in OpenIddict (and not even a standard thing).

That said, nothing prevents you from using token authentication to protect your gRPC services. For that, you can use the OpenIddict validation handler or the JWT handler. For more information regarding gRPC and authentication, you can read [Authentication and authorization in gRPC for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1).